# where can I find list of countries and states for mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

I am a php developer, I was searching for countries and states list of world in a mysql data format.
Can one help me, where can I find and download it.

Answer (score 7):

It's not in SQL format, but check out the [ISO country code list](http://www.iso.org/iso/english_country_names_and_code_elements).

Interestingly enough, you can get these as [databases](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_databases.htm) (ISO claim these are databases, but they look like spreadsheets to me!). Not free, however.

EDIT: Now that first link requires payment, I would perhaps check the current [ISO-3166 Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1).

Comment: You can download them from the ISO website in XML or delimited-text formats, which should be a piece-of-cake to import into MySQL: http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists.htm

Comment: No longer available for free - all paid.

Comment: @bandrzej - Now amended. I would point out that downvoting as unhelpful a link that recommends a paid-for resource doesn't seem right. The OP didn't specifically request a free resource

Comment: @BrianAgnew - Removed the downvote.  The OR was for a free resource, then went paid-for.  Thanks for editing.

Answer (score 3):

Geonames.org (http://www.geonames.org/) has great, free, web services and also downloads of sql dumps for their entire schema.  You should check it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can get this information from [here](http://www.maxmind.com/app/worldcities), the data is a free download.  I have used this data and just created scripts to get it in the format I wanted, and then inserted it into a mysql database.  There is an excellent blog post [here](http://blog.barros.ws/2008/10/26/countrystatecity-picker-in-symfony-11/) that discusses using this data in Symfony(a php framework)

Answer (score 0):

[Countries and States with Phone codes and ISO](https://github.com/vdeshan/countries-and-states)

This includes CSV and json files with foreign keys from states to countries.